# Persistence of AR(2) Processes

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, descriptive-statistics

The persistence of an AR(1) process is summarized by the autocorrelation parameter. That is, if the process follows

$$ y_{t} = \rho y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t,  \quad \epsilon_t \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2), $$

then the parameter $\rho$ summarizes its persistence.

Is there an analogous one dimensional measure of the persistence of an AR(2) process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an AR$(1)$ model, the ACF of $r_t$ is $\rho_l=\phi_1rho_{l-1}$. We can see why it's called persistence, since it gives the magnitude and direction of the autocorrelation function.

For an AR$(2)$, we have $\rho_l=\phi_1rho_{l-1}+\phi_2rho_{l-2}$, so you see that it's not clear cut which criteria to use to measure 'persistence'.

Check this [ECB paper on inflation](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp450.pdf?bbb5f5200ec3e701255ef3a010a87f94). It talks a bit on that subject.

P.S.: I'm not very knowledgeable, and this is just my attempt at answering your question. I hope someone can answer your question better.