# More AR lags means more persistence?

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $x_t$ is an ARMA(p,q) stochastic variable and that $y_t$ is another stochastic process that satisfies

$$ y_t = \frac{1}{(1-\rho_1 L)\cdots(1-\rho_n L)} x_t, $$

where $L$ is the lag operator, and $|\rho_i|<1$, for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

> Can I say that $y_t$ is more persistent than $x_t$? Otherwise, is there a term more accurate than persistent that I could use as in ''$y_t$ is more *[blank]* than $x_t$''?

Comment: I think you’re going to have to quantify “persistence”...

Comment: @TheLaconic Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: How do you measure/define “persistence”?

Comment: Well, that is kind of my question.

Comment: On a separate note, I don’t see any reason why that  transformation above wouldn’t just as well produce white noise, which is as un-persistent as you could like.  Specifically, consider the ARIMA process $x = (1 - \rho_1 L) ... (1 - \rho_n L) \epsilon$

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297246/persistence-of-ar2-processes